# Android: Motorola XT720 Exchange Account Problem

Tags: android, exchange-server, motorola, android-syncadapter

I have an app published on Android Market that can save contacts to different accounts. This app allows users to choose an account to save a contact to. But a lot of Motorola users report that Exchange account is not available in the list of possible accounts.

Here's a piece of code I use to get sync adapters which can save contacts:

```
final Set<String> accountTypeSet = new HashSet<String>();

final SyncAdapterType[] syncAdapters = ContentResolver.getSyncAdapterTypes();
for( final SyncAdapterType syncAdapter : syncAdapters ) {
    if ( !syncAdapter.isKey
            && syncAdapter.isUserVisible()
            && syncAdapter.supportsUploading()
            && ContactsContract.AUTHORITY.equals( syncAdapter.authority ) )
    {
        accountTypeSet.add( syncAdapter.accountType );
    }
}
```

As far as I understand Exchange account on Motorola devices violates some of conditions from this code. But I don't have any Motorola device to reproduce the problem. In my opinion Motorola Exchange `SyncAdapterType.authority` value may differ from `ContactsContract.AUTHORITY`. But it's only an assumption. What can be the real reason of this problem?